# xman and the types of documentations - help files - that are exclusive for xman

Tags: documentation, helpfile

what is the difference of `xman` from `man`. And what kind of help files can be exclusively browsed with `xman`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xman` is a graphical tool from `x11-apps` packages which allows you to browse into all manual pages installed in system using a simple GUI, based on sections (Category: is it a system call, files man, etc), lets you run searchs, `apropos`, etc.

For example you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to open up a search window:

[image]

Then you can search for a man pages or run `apropos` for specific word.

It's same as `man` with a GUI.

Here is the directory of manual pages for system calls:

[image]

[Read more](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xman)